# PHP Passing Input values through href to another page

Tags: php

```
 <input type="text" name="a" id="a" />
 <a href="xxx.php?id = <? echo '$data['id']' ?>&mk=">CLICK</a>
```

Now this is my question that can we pass an input tag value of HTML to 'mk' so that value can be used in the next page for process.
Though i have done my project in a different way but still i want to know wether is it possible to do so .
I have searched a lot but none of the question is same as i got so plz help me out.
And i dnt want to use form so i just want to know can we pass this value using href tag r not.

This is the code i have

```
<form  method="post">
    <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" border="1">
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>PRODUCT</th><th>PRICE</th><th>DATE OF POST</th><th>PHONE NUMBER</th><th>AUTHENTICATE</th></tr>
        <?
        $sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addunauth WHERE adminauthorize = 'uncheck'") or die("CANNOT FETCH DATA FOR ADMIN " . mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($sel) > 0) {
            while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {
                ?>      <tr>
                    <td><? echo $data['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $data['product_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $data['product_sp']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $data['product_time']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $data['phoneNumber']; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="a" id="a" /></td>


                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="processadminTask.php?id=<? echo $data['id']; ?>&mk=" >
                            AUTHENTICATE
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    <?
    }
} else {
    ?>          <tr><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>

        <? }
        ?>
    </table>

</form>
```

Now just tell me how to pass the input value

Comment: `script.php?key=value` will run `script.php` which can access `value` by `<?php echo $_GET['key']; ?>`

Comment: Chatspeak isn't allowed here. Please take the time to write proper English.

Comment: can u explain in detail please ?

Comment: sorry meagar but its urgent so iam typing bit fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable not parse inside single quotes. your `<? echo '$data['id']' ?>` should be `<?php echo $data['id'] ?>`

```
 <input type="text" name="a" id="a" />
 <a href="xxx.php?id = <?php echo $data['id'] ?>&mk=">CLICK</a>"
 <a id="link" href="xxx.php?id=111&mk=">CLICK</a>
```

**Edit:-**
simply add one more hidden fields to store id value as well and get value in js and assign to href

```
 <input type="text" name="idval" id="idval" value="100" />
 <input type="hidden" name="mk" id="mkval" value="101" />
```

**Js:-**

```
var idval = $('#idval').val();
var mk = $('#mkval').val();
var link = 'xxx.php?id=' + idval + '&mk=' + mk;

$("#link").attr("href", link);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxLkN/1/)</kbd>

Comment: @Rohit Dubey: try this it may help you.

Comment: thanku!! typed wrongly ... but i just want to know can we pass input value to href r not

Comment: Check my demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<? echo '$data['id']' ?>
```

Is wrong PHP Syntax

Use

```
<?php echo $data['id']; ?>
```

Like:

```
<a href="xxx.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>&mk=">CLICK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
<? echo '$data['id']' ?>
```

is not correct. You can actually use something like this

```
<?= $data['id'] ?>
```

so you'll have

```
<a href="xxx.php?id = <?= $data['id'] ?>&mk=">CLICK</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible with javascript:

```
 getElementById('id of html input').value
```

This will get you the input value and then you can assign it to 'mk'
So you can check with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$data['id'] = 2;
?>
<html>
 <input type="text" name="a" id="a" />
 <a href="xxx.php?id=<?=$data['id'];?>&mk=">CLICK</a>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a[href]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var inputTagID = $('#a').val();
    var hrefVal = this.toString().replace("&mk=", "&mk="+inputTagID); 
    window.location = hrefVal;
});
});
</script>
</html>
```